# Java Maven project - Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Tags: java, maven, heroku, crash

I have a project that I tried to deploy on Heroku. It runs perfectly find for the first 90 seconds after which it crashes. The error log is:

> 2017-02-25T16:10:12.697112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot
>   timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of
>   launch 2017-02-25T16:10:12.697112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping
>   process with SIGKILL 2017-02-25T16:10:12.802348+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 137 2017-02-25T16:10:12.812972+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>
> C:\Users\potterboi\Desktop\java-app>Error R10 (Boot
>   timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of
>   launch

The procfile is as follows:

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar`

I am not using any reference to PORT or anything else in the code. I don't know what is wrong. Could anyone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you've configured it as `web`. Since your program isn't a webapp, you need to configure it as a `worker` process in the Procfile instead. Take a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku

You can try the following Procfile which should work:

`worker: java -jar target/*.jar`

Comment: I am [getting this error too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200946/error-r10-boot-timeout-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-90-second) but in my case it *is* a web app. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Check if your port is being exposed, common problems etc.