# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot Application to Heroku but I keep getting:

```
2018-05-06T14:41:35.181889+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2018-05-06T14:41:35.182093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-05-06T14:41:35.482221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-05-06T14:41:35.496155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've seen some answers which tell me so place

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

in my application property but it is still not working.

I don't see anything else what I can do and there's no further output that could hint me to the root of the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to specify your own port? Could you please post your Procfile?

Comment: @jusermar10 According to Herokus documentation I do not need a Procfile. Since it is a Spring Boot Application everything is getting detected automatically. From what I understood it should not be necessary to set the port using `$PORT` but I might have overlooked something here ..

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old issue, however someone who gets this error message may pass by, here... So I'd like to share my solution to this issue:

I have been using the Maven Heroku Plugin in my Spring Boot Application

```
                    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

What happened to me is that accidently my POM-File got reformatted and therefore the contents within the <processTypes> <web>-Tag received some line-breaks.

The Heroku Maven Plugin creates a Procfile out of these contents. However the Procfile cannot deal with line-breaks in the commands.

So, after almost going crazy, I found out that a line-break caused the command to be corrupted and this caused the above error in my case.